# Getting wrong length on dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, events, dialog

I'm working with jquery and I'm trying to listen for how may are there open after I close a dialog, but I'm getting how many where open.
For example: if I have 4 and I close one it returns 4 when I expect to get 3, and at the end when I have only 1 open it returns 2, and at the end the when I close the last one return 1.

Am I doing right? I try look in the docs and try to look for something like afterClose but there is not.

```
$( ".test" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          height:   "auto",
          width:    "auto",
          modal:    true,
          close:    function(e){
              $(this).destroy();
              // This returns wrong lenght
              console.log($('.test').length);
              if($('.test').length === 1) {
                        console.log($('.test a').text());
              }
          }  
});
```

Comment: Perhaps the callback function isn't waiting until after the modal has completely closed?

Comment: @Blazemonger Any way to do it ?

Comment: Please provide a complete, self-contained example that reproduces your problem, either here or on a site like http://jsfiddle.net or http://codepen.io

Comment: You may be able to simply add a short `setTimeout`to your length-testing code.

Comment: An ID (#test) should only exist once on each page. If you are counting lots of instances of a dialogue you will need to change these to classes e.g. `$('.test').dialogue()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you getting those numbers?  Unless you are destroying dialogs calling

$('.test').length

is always going to return the number of classes of test on the dom.  Are you using .remove() or something to remove the dialogs? More information is needed.

When you close a dialog it does not remove it from the DOM.  It just hides it,  you can see the hidden html at the bottom of the page.  The proper way to use multiple dialogs is to use [instances](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/widget-method-invocation/) of dialogs.  but that shit is complicated.  Post some more of your code, specifically how you are setting up your html and if you are some how deleting dialogs.

Also (since i cant comment yet), the close event fires as the window is closing but before the window is hidden, this allows you two places to cancel the close event, beforeClose (typically for some validation), and close (maybe where you do some population of objects or something).

Comment: That is extremely important information.  Include that next time.

Just take the count of them after you call .destroy.


destoryFunction(){
$(this).dialog('destroy');
$(".test").length === 1
// etc.
}

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `jQuery` selector to search for visible items:

```
$( ".test" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height:   "auto",
      width:    "auto",
      modal:    true,
      close:    function(e){
          // This returns wrong lenght
          console.log($('.test:visible').length);
          if($('.test:visible').length === 1) {
                    console.log($('.test a').text());
          }
      }  
});
```

[Source](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Comment: what @Blazemonger was right the function its executing before the window close.

Comment: that's not true actually. The closed dialogue isn't removed after close. Don't know why but there must be a reason for them to choose to do that.

Comment: Correct you dont want the dialog to be removed after you close it.  You want to just hide it.  Adding and remove elements from the dom is costly compared to changing a css property to display.  Checking if it is visible inside the close function won't work since the dialog has not been hidden yet.  it hides as soon as that function returns.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".test" ).dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          height:   "auto",
          width:    "auto",
          modal:    true,
          close:    function(e){
              $(this).destroy();
              // This returns wrong lenght
              console.log($('.test').length);
              if($('.test').length === 1) {
                        console.log($('.test a').text());
              }
          }  
});
```